# how to send data in view from laravel controller in the body not in url after getting callback from google socialite?

Tags: laravel, model-view-controller

```
Login Controller :
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect;


use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;

use Laravel\Socialite\Facades\Socialite;
use App\Models\User;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
   

    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after login.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    //protected $redirectTo = '/home';

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */

    public function redirectToProvider()
    {
        return Socialite::driver('google')->redirect();
    }

    /**
     * Obtain the user information from GitHub.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function handleProviderCallback()
    {
        $user = Socialite::driver('google')->stateless()->user();

        $user_status = User::whereEmail($user->getEmail())->first();

        if ($user_status) {
            auth()->login($user_status, true);

            return Redirect::route('home', ['role' => $user_status->Role]);
        } else {
            return redirect('login');
        }
    }
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    }
}

In home.blade.php :
@extends('layouts.admin')

@section('content')
<!-- Content Header (Page header) -->
<div class="content-header">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row mb-2">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <h1 class="m-0 text-dark">Dashboard</h1>
            </div><!-- /.col -->
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <ol class="breadcrumb float-sm-right">
                    <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="{{route('home')}}">Home</a></li>

                </ol>
            </div><!-- /.col -->
        </div><!-- /.row -->
    </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</div>
<!-- /.content-header -->

<!-- Main content -->
<section class="content">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <!-- Small boxes (Stat box) -->

        <!-- /.row -->
        <!-- Main row -->
        {{$role}}
        <!-- /.row (main row) -->
    </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</section>
<!-- /.content -->
@endsection

web.php :

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home/{role?}', [App\Http\Controllers\HomeController::class, 'index'])->name('home');

Route::get('login/google', [LoginController::class, 'redirectToProvider']);
Route::get('login/google/callback', [LoginController::class, 'handleProviderCallback']);
```

Question :
So my query is that i want to redirect to page with user's role data to home page.
so when i write {{$role}} in home page it says that $role is undefined. my main motive is to change content page based on the user but i could not get the data in view page. also it does send data once in URL but i forgot that code(Beginner) so kindly advice me what to do.

Answer (score 0):

use `view()` helper for that

```php
return view('home', ['role' => $user_status->Role]);
```

or if you  want redirect then use this

```php
<!-- Main content -->
<section class="content">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        {{  auth()->user()->Role  ?? '' }} // use this
    </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</section>
```

directlty u can use `auth()->user()->Role` in blade as you are logged in

Comment: Thanks brother ...  im a beginner so there might be many question please note my profile and please help me when you are free

Comment: @PrashantJani sure consider mark this answer if it  solved